# How to make several requests in a loop and wait for one to finish before doing the next one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, request-promise

I want to make several async request in a loop, but I dont know how to do for pause the current loop until the current request is finished. I tried with a await but it doesnt work, the loop still continues the normal flow, and dispatch the request as soon enters into the loop.

Here is how I make the request:

```
     const pauseLoop = function (){
        let _poke_api = " https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{pokemon_name}"
        let _pokemons = [
            'pikachu',
            'arceus',
            'dialga',
            'fasdf',
            'electivire',
            'magmortar',
            'swampert'
        ]

        function makeRequest( pokemon_name ) {
            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{

                let url = _poke_api.replace('{pokemon_name}', pokemon_name );
            
                fetch( url )
                .then( response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then( data => {
                    resolve( data )
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    reject('No existe ese pokemon');
                });

            })
        }

        function boot(){
            _pokemons.forEach( async pokemon_name => {

                await makeRequest( pokemon_name )
                    .then( response => {
                        // console.log( response )
                    })
                    .catch( error => {
                        console.error( error )
                    });

            });
        }

        return {
            boot : boot
        }
    }()

    pauseLoop.boot();
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't wait for each iteration. Just a for loop instead, and await the returned promise so that each iteration will wait for the previous one.

Comment: combining `await` with `then` doesn't make any sense.